# ReactJS component always rerenders with external library

Tags: reactjs, devexpress

I have been working with ReactJS for a while. I would say I like it.

But some components life-cycles are still fogy for me. For example, I am trying to create a component who loads data only once from server.

On `componentDidMount` I am going not only load data but use some third-party libraries (for example jQuery components).

Below I have a very simple component with button and list. When user click the button it loads some comments into the list by AJAX request and show this list to user. When we click button again we hide this list.

**So here I have questions**:

1. Why next time I click button again it triggers data loading ?
   Because we create new `ReactElement` and it executes
   `componentDidMount`.
2. How can we improve this example to load data only once?

Please, do not suggest use `display: none;`)

Feel free to execute this [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexeiberkov/aw5nkdog/6/).

```
var jsonData = {
    "comments" : [
        {id: 1, comment: "Comment 1"},
      {id: 2, comment: "Comment 2"},
      {id: 3, comment: "Comment 3"},
      {id: 4, comment: "Comment 4"}
    ]
};

var CommentsBox = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            comments: [],
            loading: true
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
       var dxInstanceElement = this.refs.dxInstanceElement;

        $(dxInstanceElement).dxDataGrid(this.getDataGridOptions());
    },

    render: function () {

        var commentsNode = this.state.comments.map(function(comment){
            return (
                <p key={comment.id}>{comment.comment}</p>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.loading && <img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/21.gif" />}
                <div>Total count of comments: {this.state.comments.length}</div>
                <div ref="dxInstanceElement" />
            </div>
        );
    },

    getDataGridOptions: function () {
        return {

            dataSource: this.getDataGridDataSource(),

            selection: {
                mode: "multiple"
            },

            columns: [{
                dataField: "comment",
                caption: "comment"
            }]
        };
    },

    getDataGridDataSource: function () {
        var self = this,
            urlAPI = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments";

        var myStore = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
            load: function (/*loadOptions*/) {

                var d = $.Deferred();

                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url: '/echo/json/',
                  data : { 
                    json: JSON.stringify( jsonData ),
                    delay: 3
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    d.resolve(data.comments, {totalCount: data.comments.length});

                    self.setState({
                      loading: false          
                    });
                  }  
              });   

              return d.promise();
            }
        });

        return new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            store: myStore
        });
    }    
});

var DemoRouterExample = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            submited: false
        };
    },

    onClick: function() {
        var submited = this.state.submited;

        this.setState({
            submited: !submited
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        var btnLabel = this.state.submited ? "hide list" : "load list";
        return (
            <div>                               
                <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>{btnLabel}</button>
                {this.state.submited && <CommentsBox />}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <DemoRouterExample />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason is that you use `{this.state.submited && <CommentsBox />}` ,when `submit` was set to false, the `CommentsBox` is unmounted. The next time you set `submit` true, `CommentsBox` is mounted again.
I suggest you using `<CountriesBox show={this.state.submited} />` instead. And in `CommentsBox` :

```
return (
    <div className={this.props.show ? '' : 'hide'}>
        <div>Total count of comments: {this.state.comments.length}</div>
        {commentsNode}
    </div>
);
```

the `hide` class just set to `display:none;`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/24758/)

NOTE that that ajax will execute immediately you render the `DemoRouterExample`. Because `CommentsBox` is always been render.

Comment: Hi. I took your advice and implemented additional variable and just hide or show needed element.

Comment: Hi, buddy, If you really don't wanna use `display:none`, you can just return a `null` in `CountriesBox` 's render function when `show` is `false`, That might be better than use `display:none;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's the problem here but I would place the Ajax call and the corresponding state at the same level. Here maybe put your Ajax call in the parent `componentdidMount` then pass it as a prop to the child.

Comment: The problem here is I get an AJAX request every time I click the button.

Comment: yep so it means your child is mounted each time you click, that's why i'm suggesting to place your call in the parent then pass the result in props. But right I'm not sure why it's behaving like that.